Why does process memory grows uncontrollably when sending images over a NetworkStream even after disposing them?
I sending a sequence of System.Drawing.Image objects over a NetworkStream.  Even though I dispose of the previous image after receiving the next image, process memory is constantly growing, which in theory should not happen, because it performs the same actions in a loop.
How can do this so that memory use stabilizes?
Below is the application code:

namespace WindowsFormsApplication344
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
             var pb = new PictureBox { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Fill, SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom };
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { new Client().Start(); });
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            delegate
            {
                foreach (var bmp in new Server().GetScreenshots())
                {
                    if (pb.Image != null) pb.Image.Dispose();
                    pb.Image = bmp;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    class Server
    {
        public IEnumerable<Image> GetScreenshots(int port = 24432)
        {
            var list = new TcpListener(port);
            list.Start();
             using (var tcp = list.AcceptTcpClient())//принимаем конект
            using (var stream = tcp.GetStream())//создаем сетевой поток
            using (var br = new BinaryReader(stream)) //создаем BinaryReader
            while (true)//делаем бесконечно
            {
                var len = br.ReadInt32();
                var arr = br.ReadBytes(len);
                using(var ms = new MemoryStream(arr))//создаем временный поток для сжатого изображения
                {
                    yield return Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Client
    {
        public void Start(string host = "localhost", int port = 24432)
        {
            var rect = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            using (var tcp = new TcpClient(host, port)) //создаем TcpClient
            using (var stream = tcp.GetStream()) //получаем сетевой поток
            using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(stream)) //создаем BinaryWriter
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height)) //создаем битмап для отправки
            using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) //создаем канву
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) //создаем временный поток для сжатого изображения
            while (true) //делаем бесконечно
            {
                gr.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, rect.Size);
                ms.Position = 0;
                bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                var arr = ms.ToArray(); //получаем массив байт
                bw.Write(arr.Length);
                bw.Write(arr);
                bw.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}

The debugger points to MemoryStream, but how to avoid this?

Which is leaking -- the client, or the server?

Also, your Client loop doesn't have any delays or pauses.  It just loops forever grabbing a screen shot over and over again.  Possibly you are just swamping the garbage collector?

Also see Understanding garbage collection in .NET.  Unlike in say c++, freeing of memory in .NET is non-deterministic.  Managed memory gets freed when the garbage collector runs, not necessarily when some reference goes out of scope, only unmanaged resources are deterministically freed by calling Dispose().  In the case of MemoryStream the backing memory is a managed byte [] array so it gets freed when the collector runs not when you call Dispose().

@dbc Do you have any ideas on how to fix memory fill? I didn't expect that simple real-time image transmission would be so complicated...

When writing high-performance .NET code, you must minimize your temporary memory allocations, and be especially careful not to not to repeatedly allocate contiguous blocks of managed memory (such as buffers) larger than 85,000 bytes, since such blocks will go on the large object heap.  This heap is not compacted automatically so allocating many items on this heap will tend to fragment memory and degrade performance.  You are allocating multiple large buffers each time you send and receive an image; I have found that this seems to be the main cause of your problem.
There are several approaches you can use to minimize such allocations that are relevant to your application:

Be sure to dispose of all disposables as soon as they are no longer need.
You are already doing this, which is great.

Use array pooling to rent and return large buffers.

Replace MemoryStream with MSFT's Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream which is available via nuget.  This package provides

A library to provide pooling for .NET MemoryStream objects to improve application performance, especially in the area of garbage collection.


Avoid unnecessary temporary byte [] array allocations. Especially avoid MemoryStream.ToArray() which copies the memory backing the stream to a freshly allocated byte array.

Use stackalloc'ed spans for small, fixed size temporary buffers.


With these points in mind I added a reference to Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream and rewrote your code as follows (using .NET 8 since you didn't specify specific a .NET version):
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static RecyclableMemoryStreamManager Manager { get; } = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GC.Collect(); // Required for GC.GetGCMemoryInfo() to return anything.
        Console.WriteLine(GCExtensions.DumpGCInfo("Initial"));

        var pb = new MyPictureBox { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Fill, SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom };
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { new Client(Manager).Start(maxScreenshots : 100); });
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
            {
                int count = 0;
                foreach (var (bmp, stream) in new Server(Manager).GetScreenshots())
                {
                    pb.InvokeIfRequired(()=>
                    {
                        using (var i = pb.Image)
                        using (var s = pb.ImageStream)
                        {
                            pb.Image = bmp;
                            pb.ImageStream = stream;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(GCExtensions.DumpGCInfo((++count).ToString()));
                    });
                }
                pb.InvokeIfRequired(()=>
                {
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    Console.WriteLine(GCExtensions.DumpGCInfo("Final"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Run ended.");
                });
            }
        );
    }
}

class Server
{
    RecyclableMemoryStreamManager Manager { get; }

    public Server(RecyclableMemoryStreamManager? manager = null) => this.Manager = manager ?? new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();

    public IEnumerable<(Image, Stream)> GetScreenshots(int port = 24432)
    {
        byte [] buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(StreamExtensions.DefaultCopyBufferSize);
        try
        {
            var list = new TcpListener(port);
            list.Start();
            using (var tcp = list.AcceptTcpClient())
            using (var stream = tcp.GetStream())
            while (true)
            {
                RecyclableMemoryStream? ms = null;
                Image? bmp = null;
                try
                {
                    if (!stream.TryReadInt64BigEndian(out var length))
                        yield break;// Network stream terminated
                    ms = Manager.GetStream(null, length);
                    //var ms = new MemoryStream(checked((int)length));
                    if (!stream.TryCopyTo(ms, length, buffer))
                    {
                        ms.Dispose();
                        yield break; // Network stream terminated or other network error
                    }
                    bmp = Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ms?.Dispose();
                    bmp?.Dispose();
                    (ms, bmp) = (null, null);
                    // TODO: decide whether to rethrow, yield break or continue in the event of an exception.
                    throw;
                }

                yield return (bmp, ms);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
        }
    }
}

class Client
{
    RecyclableMemoryStreamManager Manager { get; }

    public Client(RecyclableMemoryStreamManager? manager = null) => this.Manager = manager ?? new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();

    public void Start(string host = "localhost", int port = 24432, long? maxScreenshots = null)
    {
        var rect = Screen.PrimaryScreen?.Bounds ?? throw new ArgumentException("No current screen.");

        using (var tcp = new TcpClient(host, port)) 
        using (var stream = tcp.GetStream()) 
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height)) 
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) 
        using (var ms = Manager.GetStream()) 
        while (maxScreenshots == null || maxScreenshots.Value > 0)
        {
            ms.SetLength(0);
            gr.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, rect.Size);
            bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            ms.Position = 0;

            stream.WriteInt64BigEndian(ms.Length);
            ms.CopyTo(stream);
            stream.Flush();
            ms.SetLength(0);

            if (maxScreenshots != null)
                maxScreenshots--;
        }
    }
}    

public partial class MyPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    // Holds a weak reference to the stream backing the Image stream (if any) so that it will be disposed automatically along with the PictureBox
    WeakReference<Stream>? imageStream;

    public Stream? ImageStream 
    { 
        get => imageStream?.TryGetTarget(out var s) == true ? s : null;
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                imageStream = null;
            else if (imageStream == null)
                imageStream = new WeakReference<Stream>(value);
            else
                imageStream.SetTarget(value);
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (disposing)
        {
            ImageStream?.Dispose();
            Debug.WriteLine("Disposed ImageStream.");
        }
    }
}

Using the following extension methods:
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void InvokeIfRequired(this Control control, MethodInvoker action)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired) 
            control.Invoke(action);
        else
            action();
    }    
}

public static class StreamExtensions
{
    public const int DefaultCopyBufferSize = 81920; // From https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Stream.cs#L126
    
    public static bool TryCopyTo(this Stream source, Stream destination, long length, byte []? inBuffer = null)
    {
        if (length <= 0)
            return false;
        byte[] buffer = inBuffer ?? ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(DefaultCopyBufferSize);
        try
        {
            int bytesRead;
            while (length > 0 && (bytesRead = source.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(length > int.MaxValue ? int.MaxValue : (int)length, buffer.Length))) > 0)
            {
                destination.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                length -= bytesRead;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (buffer != inBuffer)
                ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
        }
        
        return length <= 0;
    }

    public static bool TryReadInt64BigEndian(this Stream stream, out long value)
    {
        Span<byte> lengthBytes = stackalloc byte[sizeof(long)]; 
        if (stream.Read(lengthBytes) == sizeof(long))
        {
            // TODO: if there is a chance the 8-byte long is split across frames we may need to read in a loop.
            value = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt64BigEndian(lengthBytes);
            return true;
        }
        value = default;
        return false;
    }

    public static void WriteInt64BigEndian(this Stream stream, long value)
    {
        Span<byte> lengthBytes = stackalloc byte[sizeof(long)]; 

        BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt64BigEndian(lengthBytes,value);
        stream.Write(lengthBytes);
    }
}

public static class GCExtensions
{
    public static string DumpGCInfo(string? index = null)
    {
        using var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        var TotalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
        var TotalCommittedBytes = process.PagedMemorySize64;
        var info = GC.GetGCMemoryInfo();

        return string.Join("; ", index, TotalMemory.ToString("N0"), TotalCommittedBytes.ToString("N0"), info.Index.ToString("N0"));
    }
}

And I tested 100 iterations of the following two scenarios using 64-bit release builds:

Using MemoryStream in Server.GetScreenshots():
//var ms = Manager.GetStream(null, length);
var ms = new MemoryStream(checked((int)length));

In this scenario total allocated memory and committed bytes grew rapidly, starting at 2,298,592 bytes allocated and 104,652,800 committed after the first image is received and peaking at 67,100,896 allocated and 173,576,192 committed.  After a final call to garbage collection, memory use remained at 43,381,864 allocated and 107,671,552 committed:
When      Total Allocated Total Committed
Initial   144,968         9,334,784
1         1,931,384       104,652,800
2         2,681,616       105,439,232
3         3,462,416       106,156,032
...
97        64,911,576      172,199,936
98        65,646,200      172,851,200
99        66,374,024      173,576,192
100       67,100,896      108,281,856
Final     43,381,864      107,671,552



Using RecyclableMemoryStream in Server.GetScreenshots():
var ms = Manager.GetStream(null, length);
//var ms = new MemoryStream(checked((int)length));

With this change, allocated and committed memory grew much more slowly, starting at 1,975,848 bytes allocated and 104,505,344 committed, peaking at 3,603,328 allocated / 108,404,736 committed, then dropping back to 2,767,024 / 41,521,152 after a final forced garbage collection:
When      Total Allocated Total Committed
Initial   144,968         9,228,288
1         1,975,848       104,505,344
2         2,770,528       105,402,368
3         2,778,752       105,279,488
...
97        3,579,552       108,470,272
98        3,587,240       108,400,640
99        3,595,208       108,404,736
100       3,603,328       41,984,000 
Final     2,767,024       41,521,152



Key points:

As you can see, using array pooling and RecyclableMemoryStream seems to save lots of memory, both in total allocations and large object heap fragmentation.  (Honestly I was surprised at how large the difference was.)

When you use RecyclableMemoryStream you must be careful to dispose of it as soon as it is no longer needed.  This is necessary because its Dispose() method returns its rented memory to its RecyclableMemoryStreamManager thereby making it immediately available for reuse.  (It seems like its finalizer will do this automatically, but finalizers are not run deterministically so it's better not to leave it to chance.)

Disposing of an Image does not automatically dispose of the stream from which it was created.  You must do so manually after the image is disposed.

Rather than using BinaryWriter I worked directly with streams in order to call CopyTo(), which MSFT has optimized to minimize memory buffer allocations and maximize performance.

WinForms controls are not thread safe.  If you do some work on a background thread you must invoke on the main thread to modify a control.

See Why Large Object Heap and why do we care? for a discussion of performance issues that can arise when you allocate many large buffers.

Finally, check out Understanding garbage collection in .NET.  Unlike in say c++, freeing of memory in .NET is non-deterministic. Managed memory gets freed when the garbage collector runs, not necessarily when some reference goes out of scope.  Only unmanaged resources are deterministically freed by calling Dispose(). Even if you see memory use growing in the debugger, you might not actually have a memory leak, it may simply be that the garbage collector hasn't run yet because there is plenty of memory still available for use.
That being said, if you have reason to believe a large check of memory is no longer referenced and could be collected, you can always call GC.Collect() to force a collection.  See When is it acceptable to call GC.Collect? for a discussion of tradeoffs.


